# Unable to see Dashboard in Salesforce1 Mobile app

Tags: salesforce1-app, dashboard, salesforce1-platform

I am new to SalesForce. I have created a sample Dashboard in SF using custom objects and data. My Dashboard is appearing in desktop.

But I am unable to see my created Dashboard in SalesForce1 Mobile app. I am going to the Dashboard option in left navigation pane in the app, on clicking it the page shows Recent Dashboards. On clicking Recent Dashboards nothing comes up.

Am I doing something wrong ? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance ... !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:
 - After you click on the Dashboard icon, swipe down in the dashboards screen to refresh the data. It might pop up under your 'Recent Dashboards'
 - If that doesn't work, after you click on the Dashboard icon, try searching the name of your dashboard in the 'Search Dashboards' search bar at the top of the screen.